# Find $f(x)$ for which $I_{\varphi}(k) = \int_0^{k\varphi} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x = 1$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, definite-integrals

As the question says, the problem is as follows:

**Question 1** Find a function $f \in \mathcal{C}^{\infty}([0, \infty))$ (or $f \in \mathcal{C}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$), such that $$\forall k \in \mathbb{N} : I_{\varphi}(k) =\int_0^{k\varphi} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x = 1,$$ where $\varphi \in \mathbb{R}_+$ is an arbitrary constant *one must choose at the beginning*. This means one can choose *any* constant but then it has to be the same for all $k$.

---

To rephrase the question. You have to find a continuous, infinitely-many times differentiable function, such that if we choose a ''step'' $\varphi$, no matter how many steps we make, the integral from 0 to our current position is 1.

> Example: Function $f(x) = \frac{1}{\pi}\cos^2(x)$ is element of $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ and it holds that $$\int_0^{2\pi} f(x) = 1,$$ but $$\int_0^{k\cdot2\pi} f(x) \neq 1,$$ for all $k > 1$. In fact, it holds that $$\int_0^{k\pi} \cos^2(x) \mathrm{d}x = \frac{k\pi}{2},$$ so considering a function $$\tilde{f}(x) = f(k, x) = \frac{2}{k\pi} \cos^2(x)$$ one can clearly see that it would satisfy the problem given, **but this function is not OK**, since it is a function of $k$ and $x$, not $x$ only.

---

**Question 2** The problem is the same but $f(x)$ can be any function (not necessarily differentiable and continuous) but following condition must hold: $$\mathrm{card}(\Omega) \leq \mathrm{card}(\mathbb{N}),$$ where $\Omega = \{x \in \mathbb{R} : f(x) = 0\}$.

> Example: Function $$f(x) = \begin{cases} 1; & x \in [0,1]\\0; & \mathrm{otherwise}\end{cases}$$ **is not OK**, since $\mathrm{card}(\Omega) = \mathrm{card}(\mathbb{R}) > \mathrm{card}(\mathbb{N})$.

---

**Question 3** Omit all conditions on $f(x)$. In this case, a function from example in Question 2 **is OK**. In fact, many step functions are now OK.

---

**Question 4** Prove that such function $f$ from Question 1 or Question 2 does not exist.

Have fun with this problem! :)

Comment: You can assume that $\varphi=2\pi$.  Then, take first $f(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}$ for $x\in[0,2\pi]$ (or for $x\in (-\infty,2\pi]$), and $f(x)=\cos(x)$ for $x\in(2\pi,\infty)$.  Note that $f$ satisfies the integral condition.  Of course, $f$ is not smooth.  But do you know a trick that can improve the smoothness of $f$?

Comment: This is not possible in all cases. For example, what if $\phi = 0$? You need additional restriction(s).

Comment: @MPW  The OP is very vague with his question.  Botond mentioned one error.  I think $\varphi$ is supposed to be a fixed constant, and $I$ is supposed to be a function with a positive integer argument $k$.

Comment: @Botond indeed, my mistake, corrected the question

Comment: @Batominovski $I$ is a function of parameter $\varphi$ but once you choose your $\varphi$, it is constant. Maybe better notation would be $I_{\varphi}$. I will try to be more explicit

Comment: @campovski  The problem is your problem statement makes it sound like $f$ does not depend on $\varphi$.  As MPW pointed out, you should make it clear that $\varphi$ is fixed first, then the task is to find $f$ (depending on $\varphi$) such that $I$ is constant.

Comment: @Batominovski I hope it is clear now

Comment: Definitely, Question 4 is wrong.  There exists such an $f$ which is smooth and has countably many zeros.  It would be a challenge to determine whether there exists an analytic $f$ satisfying the integral condition.

Comment: @Batominovski is right. It's not hard to see that they exist using bump functions.

Comment: You should just require $\phi >0$ because the integral doesn't make sense if $\phi<0$ (because always $k>0$) -- at least if you are also requiring the domain of $f$ to be $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: @Batominovski Yes, but does such $f$ satisfies the integral condition? That is the problem. There might be such functions but if there are none, then the question 4 might also be eligible, I think

Comment: @campovski Read my first comment again, and maybe a hint from Fimpellizieri.

Comment: @MPW good point, thanks

Comment: @campovski A bump function does satisfy the integral condition.  You only need to choose a bump function $b(x)$ such that the support of $b$ is $[0,1]$.  Then, $$f(x):=\frac{b(x)}{\int_0^1\,b(t)\,\text{d}t}$$ will work.  You need to work more if you want to have countably many zeros.  I already provided you with an answer.

Comment: Indeed, was just wanting to write that. So question 1 has been answered, now we need Question 2. Someone gonna write an answer to question 1 as answer?

Comment: One more comment:  Did you mean to write $\mathcal{C}^\infty\big([0,\infty)\big)$ instead of $\mathcal{C}^\infty\big([0,\infty]\big)$?

Comment: @batominovski indeed, my mistake. I think the question is not too broad tho, it consists of multiple questions but they are strongly related. The question was meant as a task and subquestions serve as hints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that the OP meant $\mathcal{C}^\infty\big([0,\infty)\big)$, rather than $\mathcal{C}^\infty\big([0,\infty]\big)$ (the answer would definitely change if I was wrong about this).  I am answering Questions 1, 2, and 4 simultaneously.

Let $b_\varphi:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ be a bump function with support $\left[\frac{\varphi}{2},\varphi\right]$.  Define
$$B_\varphi(x):=\frac{\int_{-\infty}^x\,b_\phi(t)\,\text{d}t}{\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\,b_\varphi(t)\,\text{d}t}\text{ for every }x\in\mathbb{R}\,.$$
Consider the function
$$\psi(x):=\big(1-B_\varphi(x)\big)+B_\varphi(x)\,\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{\varphi}x\right)\text{ for each }x\in\mathbb{R}\,.$$
Then, $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$f(x):=\frac{\psi(x)}{\int_0^\varphi\,\psi(t)\,\text{d}t}\text{ for all }x\in\mathbb{R}$$
satisfies the smoothness condition, the integral condition, and the countability condition on $f^{-1}(0)$, as
$$f^{-1}(0)=\varphi\,\mathbb{Z}_{>0}=\Biggl\{\left(k+\frac{1}{2}\right)\varphi\,\Big|\,k\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}\Biggr\}\,.$$

**P.S.** It is an interesting challenge to show whether there exists an analytic function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ (or $f:\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}\to\mathbb{R}$) obeying the integral condition.  I conjecture that the answer is negative.